# How do I check whether an index of array is empty and then, if it is, skip to the next?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to build a program that can register a user to the database (still learning cpp, I hope that in the near future I'll be able to work with database).

What I'm trying to do with this code is to check whether an index of array is empty for the user to store an ID in it. If it isn't empty, I want the program to keep looking for an empty index of array, for the new info to be stored in.

Here is the code:

```
void registro() {
std::string userid[3];
userid[0] = "Houkros"; // eventually I'll try to have this being read from a file or server database..
std::string userpass[3];
std::string usermail[3];
std::string userkey[3];
std::string getUid[3];
std::string getUpass[3];
std::string getUmail[3];
std::string getUkey[3];

std::cout << std::endl << " >>>> REGISTRATION <<<< " << std::endl;
std::cout << " =============================================== " << std::endl;
std::cout << std::endl;
std::cout << "Please, enter the desired user id: " << std::flush;
if (userid[0].empty())
{
    std::cin >> userid[0];
}
else {
    std::cin >> userid[1];
}
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    std::cout << " Element of array: " << i << " is > " << userid[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: As far as I know, an element in an array is never empty. Can you give an example of how you create an array with an "empty" element? Are you aware of the concept of initialising variables?

Comment: What problem exactly do you have with the shown code? You seem to already be checking whether the zeroth id is empty. So all you need to do is keep checking the next (probably in a loop).

Comment: You might consider grouping all of those fields in a struct or class and making one array of that object instead. Normally you'd use a loop to iterate through each item until you find one where the userid is empty.

Comment: @Yunnosch These are `std::string`, so it seems "empty" here means "empty `std::string`"

Comment: @user17732522 Yes, that is why I ask whether OP knows that the array element is never empty and (implicitly) that the `empty()` is always on the non-empty content of the array, which however might be non-iniitialised and cause trouble. After all, an array element containing an empty string is not empty.

Comment: @Yunnosch Sadly I thought it would be empty... I guess I'll have to find another way to do it... any tips?

Comment: Houkros, please consider the following definitions for an "empty" array element: a) not initialised (unhelpful, cannot be checked) b) never yet written to (same as a) ) c) contains "" (possible, but means that "" must not be accepted as an actual content) d) is empty according to a second array in which that info is maintained (this is what I almost recommend e) contains a struct with a string and a maintained "empty" flag (this I recommend)  Which seems an option for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider the following definitions for an "empty" array element:
a) not initialised (unhelpful, cannot be checked)
b) never yet written to (same as a) )
c) contains `""` (possible, but means that `""` must not be accepted as an actual content)
d) is empty according to a second array in which that info is maintained (this is what I almost recommend)
e) contains a struct with a string and a maintained "empty" flag (this I recommend)

Whatever you do, make sure that you init all variables and array elements before first read-accessing them; i.e. in all cases first write something meaningful to it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll look into it and figure out what to do based on what you've explained. Since I'm new to StackOverflow, I can't upvote your answer yet, but I'll do as soon as the website let me.

Comment: It seems you are doing well, you will get there. Good introductory info (though you seem to get along without....) is here [tour].